# Check running inventory for available rental stock

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm building a website for a hypothetical rental business and I'm trying to check for available inventory over a specified time span when the user clicks the "Add to Cart" button. I'm having some trouble with the SQL query that is run, mostly (I think) due to my $product_id variable being an integer but the columns I want to query being in the form "item1", "item2", etc.

The logic I was attempting to use was to subtract the desired quantity from the number available in the table, take the minimum of those values over the given time span, and then check if, at any point, that number went below zero.

Here is the relevant code:

```
switch ($action) {
case 'view':
    $cart = cart_get_items();
    break;
case 'add':
    $product_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'product_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $quantity = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'quantity');
    $pickup = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pickup');
    $return = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'return');

    // validate the quantity entry
    if ($quantity === null) {
        display_error('You must enter a quantity.');
    } elseif (!is_valid_number($quantity, 1)) {
        display_error('Quantity must be 1 or more.');
    }

    // check for available inventory
    $query = "SELECT MIN((SELECT CONCAT('item',:product_id)) - :quantity) FROM running_inventory WHERE date BETWEEN :pickup AND :return";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':product_id', $product_id);
    $statement->bindValue(':quantity', $quantity);
    $statement->bindValue(':pickup', $pickup);
    $statement->bindValue(':return', $return);
    $statement->execute();
    $available = $statement->fetch();
    $num_avail = $available[0];
    var_dump($num_avail);
    $statement->closeCursor();
    if ($num_avail - $quantity >= 0) {
    cart_add_item($product_id, $quantity);
    } else {
        display_error('The indicated quantity of stock is not available for your rental period.');
    }
    $cart = cart_get_items();
    break;
```

And this is the var_dump for $available:

```
array(2) { ["MIN((SELECT CONCAT('item','6')) - '3')"]=> string(2) "-3" [0]=> string(2) "-3" } string(2) "-3"
```

It's obviously just subtracting $quantity from 0, but I can't seem to figure out exactly where the problem is.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to SO and a little scatterbrained at the moment. I edited the post with the var_dump.

Comment: You still have not explained the problem.  What value are you expecting to be returned? Why are you subtracting a number from a string?  Of course that's not going to work.  Why are you using the MIN function on a single value?  That's not going to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT item{$product_id} - :quantity FROM running_inventory WHERE  date BETWEEN :pickup AND :return";
```

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help. I wasn't sure how much detail of underlying table structure I should post, but I realize now that it was much more than I did. The columns in my running_inventory table are date (DATE) and one column for each of the items, each in the form itemX (INT). My main issue is that I need to select from a column called, for example, "item7", but $product_id is just an integer. I was trying to use CONCAT in the query so that I could call the correct column name, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go about things.